# opencv, get a single descriptor from a descriptors cv::Mat?

Tags: opencv

I have an opencv application in which I need to store a 2d point's coordinates, and the feature descriptor for that point.

For example, after i run the following code:

```
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1;
Mat descriptors_1;
Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = ORB::create();
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> descriptor = ORB::create();

detector->detect ( img_1,keypoints_1 );
descriptor->compute ( img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1 );
```

I get `descriptors_1`, which is every descriptor for every `Keypoint`'

How can I get the descriptor that corresponds with, for example, `keypoints_1[12]`, and store it as a Mat?

Neither descriptors_1.rows, nor descriptors_1.cols has the same size as the number of keypoints.

Comment: read row 12 of the descriptor matrix

Comment: So I can just:  `cv::Mat descriptor12 = descriptors_1.row(12);`? Why does the number of rows not equal the number of keypoints? Thank you.

Comment: the number of rows should equal the number of keypoints, afaik. The .row should give you a eow-pointer. There are tutorials online about how to access and iterate Mat objects.

Answer (score 0):

descriptor->compute may remove key points from the array - if it can't compute the descriptor for a given key point. After calling compute the two matrices should have the same number of rows.